# iterating over array with json objects

Tags: java, android-studio

```
[{"id":1,"flat_number":"b9","building_name":"ram society","locality":"kothrud","city":"pune","state":"maharashtra","landmark":"near ACC school","pincode":411038,"type":"home"},
{"id":2,"flat_number":"b9","building_name":"ram society","locality":"kothrud","city":"pune","state":"maharashtra","landmark":"near ACC school","pincode":411038,"type":"work"}]
```

this is the response array from my php web service which fetches data from mysql.
i want to display these addresses in a list view in android app.
how do i write the java code for that.
this is the code for receiving the result but i cant get any result.

```
private void getAddress() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_ADDRESS,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                            

                            flat_number = obj.getString("flat_number");
                            building_name = obj.getString("building_name");
                            locality = obj.getString("locality");
                            city = obj.getString("city");
                            state = obj.getString("state");
                            landmark = obj.getString("landmark");
                            pincode = obj.getInt("pincode");
                            type = obj.getString("type");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Data couldn't be fetched!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                }

        );

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

pls help with the java code for list view as well. and how to match this data to the adapter??

after the first answer here is what i did
code
Address.java

```
public class Address {
    public String flat_number;
    public String building_name;
    public String locality;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public String landmark;
    public int pincode;
    public String type;

    // Constructor to convert JSON object into a Java class instance
    public Address(JSONObject object){
        try {
            this.flat_number = object.getString("flat_number");
            this.building_name = object.getString("building_name");
            this.locality = object.getString("locality");
            this.city = object.getString("city");
            this.state = object.getString("state");
            this.landmark = object.getString("landmark");
            this.pincode = object.getInt("pincode");
            this.type = object.getString("type");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    // Factory method to convert an array of JSON objects into a list of objects
    // User.fromJson(jsonArray);
    public static ArrayList<Address> fromJson(JSONArray jsonObjects) {
        ArrayList<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonObjects.length(); i++) {
            try {
                address.add(new Address(jsonObjects.getJSONObject(i)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return address;

    }
}
```

AddressAdapter.java

```
public class AddressAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressHolder>{
    private List<Address> dataList;

    public AddressAdapter(List<Address> list){
        this.dataList= list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AddressHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new AddressHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AddressHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(dataList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

AddressHolder.java

```
public class AddressHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView tvFlatNumber, tvBuildingName, tvLocality, tvCity, tvState, tvLandmark, tvPincode, tvType;
    //any view you defined in item_single_item layout

    public AddressHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvFlatNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.flat_number);
        tvBuildingName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.building_name);
        tvLocality = itemView.findViewById(R.id.locality);
        tvCity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.city);
        tvState = itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);
        tvLandmark = itemView.findViewById(R.id.landmark);
        tvPincode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pincode);
        tvType = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);

    }

    public void bind(Address data) {
        tvFlatNumber.setText(data.flat_number);
        tvBuildingName.setText(data.building_name);
        tvLocality.setText(data.locality);
        tvCity.setText(data.city);
        tvState.setText(data.state);
        tvLandmark.setText(data.landmark);
        tvPincode.setText(data.pincode);
        tvType.setText(data.type);

    }
}
```

AddressActivity.java
this is where i am displaying the address i got from above JSON

this portion of code is written in onCreate method-

```
    RecyclerView addressList;
    String flat_number, building_name, locality, city, state, landmark, type;
    int pincode;

    addressList = findViewById(R.id.addressList);
    addressList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    List<Address> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    getAddress();

    // Construct the data source
    ArrayList<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    AddressAdapter addressAdapter = new AddressAdapter(dataList);

    // Attach the adapter to a ListView
    addressList.setAdapter(addressAdapter);
//on create ends
```

and in the getAddress() method-

```
try{
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            Address.fromJson(jsonArray);
}
catch(){}
```

still nothing is displayed and no error is shown in logcat.
help..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create class which consist from data you get:

```
    public class YourDataClass {
    public String id;
        public String flat_number;
        public String building_name;
        public String locality;
        public String city;
        public String state;
        public String landmark;
        public String pincode;
        public String type;
    
        public YourDataClass(String id, String flat_number, String building_name, String locality, String city,
                             String state, String landmark, String pincode, String type) {
this.id = id
            this.flat_number = flut_number;
            this.building_name = building_number;
            this.locality = locality;
            this.city = city;
            this.state = state;
            this.landmark = landmark;
            this.pincode = pincode;
            this.type = type;
        }
    }
```

In Activity class you make `List<YourDataClass> dataList = new ArrayList()<>;`
Then you can populate adapter with this data.
I suggest to use not ListView, but RecyclerView because it is easyer to maintain and has better perfomance.
So in layout of your activity instead of ListView add

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then in activity do this in onCreate:

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_list)
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this))
```

When your dataList is ready make this:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new YourAdapter())
```

Adapter code:

```
public class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourHolder>{
    private List<YourDataClass> dataList;

    public YourAdapter(List<YourDataClass> list){
        this.dataList= list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public YourHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_single_item, parent, false);
        return new YourHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull YourHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(dataList.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

R.layout.item_single_item - is layout for single list item.
YourHolder code:

```
public class YourHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private final TextView tvFlatNumber;
    private final TextView tvBuildingNumber;
    //any view you defined in item_single_item layout

    public YourHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvFlatNumber= itemView.findViewById(R.id.flat_number);
        tvBuildingNumber= itemView.findViewById(R.id.building_number);
       //and so on

    }

    public void bind(YourDataClass data) {
        tvFlatNumber.setText(data.flat_number)
//and so on
    }
```

The code of item_single_item can be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border_background"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/flat_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/building_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/flat_number" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

EDIT:

```
private void getAddress() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_ADDRESS,
                new com.android.volley.Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                             JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                             ArrayList<Address> address = Address.fromJson(jsonArray);
AddressAdapter addressAdapter = new AddressAdapter(dataList);
addressList.setAdapter(addressAdapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Data couldn't be fetched!",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show();
                    }
                }

        );

        RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: i made some updates to the question as per your answer. can u pls check again?

Comment: problem is here - List<Address> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    getAddress();

Comment: You initialize List<Address> dataList inside of onCreate call of your Activity.  And then call outside method - getAdress(). After that you pass empty dataList to your AddressAdapter. To solve this just change List<Address> dataList = new ArrayList<>() to List<Address> dataList = getAddress();

Comment: If it will not help then you have a problem while you parsing JSONArray in fromJson method or in Address class constructor. but I am sure you will solve your problem after you read my previous comment

Comment: changed the dataList as you asked and when i log it it shows null that means there is some error while parsing in fromJSON method. what do i do now?

Comment: can you debug your code? I suggest you to put stop point inside try {} body at first line at public Address(JSONObject object) constructor. Is that object is JSON object? Does it has right keys? and so on

Comment: By the way, tell me what is inside your getAdress method you call in onCreate? If it is the one you posted at top of your question  I guess it is asyncronyous, so  you suppose to setAdapter in onResponse method

Comment: Look at EDIT section of my answer